# Function that returns a bool result and show errors in case of a false return

Tags: algorithm, error-handling, boolean, throw

I want to have a function that validate an object.

In case of a false result I want to know the reason why my object isn't valid.

This is a sample algorithm:

```
public bool ValidObject(MyObjectClass obj)
{
   if(obj==null)
   {
       throw Exception("obj cannot be null");
       return false;
   }

   if(obj.A=='x'){
       throw Exception("obj cannot be x");
       return false;
   }
    ....
    ....
    // other validations
    ....
    ...

   if(obj.Students.Count()==100)
   {
       throw Exception("some error message");
       return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

If I call my function:

```
if(ValidateObject(this.Obj))
{
   InsertIntoDB(this.Obj);
}
else
{
   //do something 
}
```

I will get an error if my object is invalid. But I dont't want this.

But maybe in some cases I want to know the reason why my object is invalid.

I don't want to make to functions that do the same but one of them throw exceptions. I don't think is a right approach.

So, my first thought was to make the previous function private and to create another public function:

```
public bool ValidObject2(MyObjectClass obj, bool withErrors=false)
{
  try
  {
     return ValidObject(obj);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    if(withErrors)
    {
       throw ex;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

What do you think? Do you have other ideas ?

Comment: Why don't you use 'try..catch' directly in the caller?

Answer (score 0):

The Rails way:

Have a method `save` which saves to the DB, and, in case of validation errors, just holds on to them without raising an exception.

Provide a getter `validation_errors` which returns a list of the errors in the previous `save`.

Make a trivial method `save_with_validation` which first calls `save` and then raises an exception if and only if `validation_errors` returns a non-empty set of errors. (Depending on your language, you might be able to get away with a shorter name like `save!`)